# dependsOnGroups annotation in Test NG

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, annotations, automated-tests

@Test(groups = { "init" })
public correctVM() {}

@Test(groups = { "init" })
public serverStartedOk() {}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init.* })
public method1() {}

// Above TestNG code

in method1, for the dependsOnGroups regular expression is used. Is it mandatory to use regEx or is it okay to give "init" as all groups are having name as init.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you use the regex will TestNG know that you are not giving an absolute group name but you are indicating a pattern.
So going by your example you would need to mention

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "init.* }) 
public method1() {
    //code goes here.
}
```

for TestNG to basically pick up any groups whose names begin with `init`